# Most stable version of Spring 4.x . Upgrade needed from 3.0.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jms, spring-framework-beans

I want to upgrade my application from spring 3.0.5 version to Spring 4.x version, and I would like to know which one is the most stable(no bugs).. thanks for your help :)

I want to know the Major and Minor version we should use for the upgrade please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often with most libraries/frameworks, the best place to find this answer is the project webpage : http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/

You will find on the right the latest versions stable and not stable (SNAPSHOT).
At the moment of writing this answer, `4.3.11` is the latest stable release of v4.X.X.

FYI, Spring 5 has been released a few days ago.

Another way to find latest dependencies, that will work for most OSS project is to look at [Maven central repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-core%22)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Matt. Also, considering we are upgrading from version 3.0.5 to say 4.3.11. Would that be a simple case of just updating the libraries or, do you think there may be other dependencies which we need to look at.

Comment: It should be ok, but you'll probably have to adapt some config. Spring provides a guide for migration : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Migrating-to-Spring-Framework-4.x